# How to count how many times a specific value in a dictionary of dictionaries in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know there must be a very simple solution to this question but I am new with Python and cannot figure out how to do it.

All I simply want to do is count how many times a particular value appears in this dictionary, for example, how many males there are.

```
people = {}
people['Applicant1'] = {'Name': 'David Brown',
                        'Gender': 'Male',
                        'Occupation': 'Office Manager',
                        'Age': '33'}
people['Applicant2'] = {'Name': 'Peter Parker',
                        'Gender': 'Male',
                        'Occupation': 'Postman',
                        'Age': '25'}    
people['Applicant3'] = {'Name': 'Patricia M',
                        'Gender': 'Female',
                        'Occupation': 'Teacher',
                        'Age': '35'}
people['Applicant4'] = {'Name': 'Mark Smith',
                        'Gender': 'Male',
                        'Occupation': 'Unemployed',
                        'Age': '26'}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you have applicants and their data. The data you are checking is their gender, so the below code will accomplish that.

```
amount = 0                                       # amount of people matching condition
for applicant in people.values():                # looping through all applicants
    if applicant.get('Gender', False) == 'Male': # checks if applicant['Gender'] is 'Male'
                                                 # note it will return False if ['Gender'] wasn't set
        amount += 1                              # adds matching people to amount
```

This will get the amount of males in the applicant list.

Comment: Returning `"Female"` instead of `False` would work the same, and be a little less jarring than the resulting `False == "Male"` comparison.

Comment: That's true, but just incase the OP wanted to change the info checked with 'Female', it won't do anything "unexpected".

Comment: No problem. Have a great day :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a function to count the number of occurrences of a given value inside a dictionary:

```
def count(dic, val):   
        sum = 0
        for key,value in dic.items():
            if value == val:
                sum += 1
            if type(value) is dict:
                sum += count(dic[key], val)
        return sum
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
result = count(people, 'Male')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest refactoring your logic a bit to use a list of dicts.

```
people = [
    {
        'Name': 'David Brown',
        'Gender': 'Male',
        'Occupation': 'Office Manager',
        'Age': '33'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Peter Parker',
        'Gender': 'Male',
        'Occupation': 'Postman',
        'Age': '25'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Patricia M',
        'Gender': 'Female',
        'Occupation': 'Teacher',
        'Age': '35'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'Mark Smith',
        'Gender': 'Male',
        'Occupation': 'Unemployed',
        'Age': '26'
    }
]
```

Then you can use logic like

```
[applicant for applicant in people if applicant['Gender'] == 'Male']
```

Which will give you all of the males in the list

Comment: So would `[applicant for applicant in people.values() if applicant['Gender'] == 'Male']`. Switching from a `dict` to a `list` without knowing why a `dict` was used in the first place isn't particularly useful.